# custom post page template

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a problem with this script which should load a custom template when view a custom post page.

I've place a echo command to make sure that the url is correct but i doesn't even echo the url.

```
function da_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
     global $post;

     if ($post->post_type == 'include') {

          $single_template = PLUGIN_PATH. 'template/custom_template.php';
     }
     echo $single_template;
     return $single_template;
}
add_filter( "single_template", "da_custom_post_type_template" ) ;
```

Please help

Comment: try to echo "test"; and check it is echoing or not... we will know it is inside the function

Comment: No it doesn't see to echo inside the function..... :(

Comment: @DavidAllen how u r passing $single_template to your method??? ;)

Comment: No i'm just coping this http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template

Comment: Just tried it without and i still doesn't work... :(

Comment: @DavidAllen  does this exists " post-type-template.php "  ??? please refer like "@" so that i get the notification

Comment: OK i have found out that the "single_template is not used now..."  does anyone know what to replace it with..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally done it....

I re downloaded wordpress and change my code to below...

gobal $post didn't seem to have anything set so i used $wp_query instead.  Thanks CroiOS for pointing that out.

And also thanks to CMF for point me into the right direction with my installation on word press issue.  i installed WP via SSH so i'm wondering if I downloaded a nightly build or something like that..

```
function da_custom_post_type_template( $template ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if ($wp_query->post->post_type == 'include') {
      $template = PLUGIN_PATH . '/template/custom_template.php';
    }
    return $template ;
}
add_filter( "archive_template", "da_custom_post_type_template" ) ;
```

Also for some reason its class as a archive_template :)

Answer (score 1):

Put this into single.php:

```
<?php
      global $wp_query;

      $post = $wp_query->post;
      $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');

      if($post_type == 'include'){
        include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/my_post_template.php');
      }else{
        include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/default_post_template.php');
      }#end else

?>
```

Comment: im making a plugin so i can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can still filter single template, actually. It still exists on `wp-includes/template.php`.

<strike>I can't see nothing wrong on your function. Are you sure that the template file is exists?</strike>

Edit:

Try this:

```
function da_custom_post_type_template( $template ) {
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type == 'include') {
        $template = dirnamr( __FILE__ ) . '/template/custom_template.php';
    }
    return locate_template( $template );
}
add_filter( "single_template", "da_custom_post_type_template" ) ;
```

Comment: I don't have a template.php in my wp-includes folder.

Comment: I've re downloaded the wordpress and now a have a template.php